# Pandas - How to calculate duration of groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
ID DATE                Remark
A  2020-06-22 16:10:00 P
A  2020-06-22 11:00:00 F
A  2020-06-22 10:50:00 P
B  2020-06-22 15:15:00 P
B  2020-06-22 15:10:00 F
A  2020-06-22 10:40:00 F
B  2020-06-22 15:00:00 F
```

I want something like

```
ID DATE                Duration Remark
A  2020-06-22 11:10:00 null     P
A  2020-06-22 11:00:00 05:10:00 F
A  2020-06-22 10:50:00 null     P
A  2020-06-22 10:40:00 00:10:00 F
B  2020-06-22 15:15:00 null     P
B  2020-06-22 15:10:00 00:05:00 F
B  2020-06-22 15:00:00 00:10:00 F
```

The dtype of DATE is datetime64 and is already arranged in descending order.
The Duration for remark P will always be null or 0.
I guess I need to write something like `df.groupby('ID')['DATE']....` but how exactly should I code it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def random_dates(start, end, n=10):
    # generating random TS
    start_u = start.value//10**9
    end_u = end.value//10**9 
    return pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start_u, end_u, n), unit='s')

start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
dates = random_dates(start, end)
remark = ['P', 'F', 'P', 'F', 'P', 'F', 'P', 'F', 'P', 'F']
ids = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(ids, dates,remark), columns=["ID", "DATE", "REMARK"]) # creating the df
# will return the difference as needed but you might have to format it as per your need;
df.groupby("ID")["DATE"].diff()
```

Comment: Since DATE is already sorted in descending, ```diff()``` seems to work quite well but why do i receive ```-1 days +23:50:00``` these kind of result instead of ```00:10:00```?

Comment: You need to re-format the difference returned as per your needs;

Answer (score 1):

use `.groupby` with `.cumcount()` to identify the difference in groups and filter by > 0 to ignore the first row of that group. Then use `.shift` to compare to previous row and get the time differnece:

input:

```
   ID  DATE                 Duration  Remark
0  A   2020-06-22 11:10:00  null      P
1  A   2020-06-22 11:00:00  05:10:00  F
2  A   2020-06-22 10:50:00  null      P
3  A   2020-06-22 10:40:00  00:10:00  F
4  B   2020-06-22 15:15:00  null      P
5  B   2020-06-22 15:10:00  00:05:00  F
6  B   2020-06-22 15:00:00  00:10:00  F
```

code:

```
# commented the following line out asuming that it is in datetime format. If not, then use the below line.
# df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['Duration'] = np.where((df.groupby('ID').cumcount() > 0), (df.shift()['DATE'] - df['DATE']), np.nan)
```

output:

```
    ID  DATE                Duration    Remark
0   A   2020-06-22 11:10:00 NaT         P
1   A   2020-06-22 11:00:00 00:10:00    F
2   A   2020-06-22 10:50:00 00:10:00    P
3   A   2020-06-22 10:40:00 00:10:00    F
4   B   2020-06-22 15:15:00 NaT         P
5   B   2020-06-22 15:10:00 00:05:00    F
6   B   2020-06-22 15:00:00 00:10:00    F
```

Comment: Nice Approach; +1!

Comment: Why do i receive result like ```-1 days +23:50:00``` instead of ```00:10:00```?

Comment: @CheangWaiBin I had to reformat your data with two spaces and then used this code to read in the data `df = pd.read_clipboard('\s+\s+')` See my updated answer with input. This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It may be valid for the sample data only, but you can sort the data chronologically, calculate the difference, and restore the original order by Sort by. One more line shifted.

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df.sort_values('DATE',inplace=True)
df['Duration'] = df['DATE']-df['DATE'].shift()
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].shift()

df
    ID  DATE    Remark  Duration
0   A   2020-06-22 11:10:00 P   NaT
1   A   2020-06-22 11:00:00 F   00:10:00
2   B   2020-06-22 15:15:00 P   NaT
3   B   2020-06-22 15:10:00 F   00:05:00
4   B   2020-06-22 15:00:00 F   00:10:00
```

Comment: This seems to be closer to what I want but there will be cases where A will have time later than B

Comment: I'm aware of that; I'd have to split up the DF by ID to deal with that. I'm sorry I can't help you.